# What is the relation between Fragments, Activities, and Layout/Menu XML files in Android Programming?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

So, I'm a beginner to Android programming, but not new to Java. If relevant, I'm using Android Studio. I was wondering, is there only ONE java file for my whole project? It's called "MainActivity", is this the only Java file I use for my project? If not, how or why would I create another one, and does that have anything to do with creating a new activity? Are activities discreet screens, and if so, isn't it possible to create discrete screens in a single activity? I understand fragments, but also, are Layout/Menu files independent to one activity, or are they for the whole project? Sorry for the barrage of questions :p. Thanks!

Comment: You have one Application.class that is initiated at the start of your app. You can store your singletons there and can access them from any activity or fragment. You can have many Activities, but you can also have one Activity and only changing Fragments and Actionbar styles from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a nutshell:

An [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) is something the user interacts with. The documentation states

> An activity is a single, focused thing that the user can do. Almost all activities interact with the user, so the Activity class takes care of creating a window for you in which you can place your UI with

A [Fragment](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) is part of the user interface. Fragments can be added to an Activity to display content and used as parts of dynamic UIs.

A Layout XML file will define what the Fragment looks like (what Views are in it, how they are laid out) or what the Activity's View hierarchy looks like.

A Menu XML file will be for options in the menu. A menu isn't necessary.

In short, an Activity may contain Fragments or may not. An Activity will be what the user sees and interacts with, generally. There usually isn't a single Java file in your application but if there was it would likely be an Activity.

This is a very general question. Looking over the documentation and reading the Android API guides will be very helpful.

Comment: Up voting because this pretty much answer the question the OP asked and also troll down voters who silently down vote without providing suggestions for improvement/reason don't really help the community.